# Fixing the oldest bug about serialVersionUID from jasperreports with barcode

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

This thread is about an oldest bug from jasperreports containing barcode. All Java Swing clients get an exception about *serialVersionUID* when they are trying to print a remote compiled report, this one downloaded through RMI, HTTP request, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Swing clients only can see those reports who were rendered by the same JVM version (server), this one for instance:

1. JVM Server: 1.7.0.71
2. JVM Client: 17.0.71

### But, how we can fix it ?

The first option we have is render those reports as PDF format. For instance:

```
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFile, parameters, connection);
byte[] bi= JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
```

Then return this byte array for clients, so read/write it as PDF stream to local temp file on client side. This one can by mobile, desktop, web, etc.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/some/file.pdf");
fos.write(bytes);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

The second one, but I think more simple and transparent, is replace the barcode lib that you're using on your reports, from **Barbecue** to **Barcode4J**. The image bellow shows what lib you must choose:
[image]

And, to keep the same proportion of Barbecue lib of Code 128, you should sets 'Module width' option with value '1.0'.
[image]

### Other tips

In general, always render reports in PDF there aren't no problems, it's more responsive through clients (web, desktop, mobile, etc.), except when you're working if labels (or stickers), *PIMACO 6082* for instance. When you convert jasper to PDF, RTF, or any other format, sometimes their margins are modified in this process.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you wish to post in a Q&A format, remove the "solution" from your post and move it down below as it's own answer submission.

Comment: Ok, I'll do this. Thanks